# Is KdepimLibs 4.12.44 package available now?

Tags: 13.10, package-management, versions

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, Linux version 3.11.0-15-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) ).

To build one of the application I need KdepimLibs5-dev 4.12.44. But on apt-get upgrad it  upgrades to 4.11.x. Please help!

Comment: KdepimLibs5-dev  4.12.1 is available on PPA.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Which PPA?

Comment: @landron `kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/`